# access 2010 server filter vs normal filter

Tags: vba, filter

I am working on an Access 2010 front-end and I am trying to understand the difference between the server filter and the so called standard filter. I only seem to get the results I am looking for (when opening a form for example) when using the normal filter, and poor results with the serverfilter.

Could someone share with me some knowledge on this topic.

Thank you very much!
Vincent